# Launcher crashes when unlocking my x touch tablet

Tags: applications, calendar

When I unlock my tablet a "calendar has stopped working" message appears. After clicking "ok" I see another message "unfortunately launcher has stopped".

How can I stop this happening?

Comment: Do you have any calendar widgets on your homescreen?

Comment: A "generic approach" to that kind of trouble is to boot into recovery, and "wipe cache" (no data loss, it's just "temp files"). Sometimes things get messed up there, so cleaning cache solves it. Have you tried that? Did it help?

Answer (score -1):

Well, I guess you launcher is experiencing problems with the your Android device. I would say if the problem persist first try clearing the cache and the data store by the launcher app, you can do that by heading over to the settings>application manager>Tap over the launcher and clear the cache and the data stored. Now try opening the launcher again and see if it shows you the same error again. If it pops up again then I would say better to uninstall the application. Rest I'll leave it upto you!